# Iniciando em Programação

Tags: c, eclipse

Elaborei um algorítimo bem simples, porém não estou conseguindo executar o mesmo.

Segue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num1, num2, soma, multiplicacao;

int main(){
    printf("informe primeiro número: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("informe segundo número: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    soma = num1 + num2;
    multiplicacao = soma * num1;

    printf("o resultado é %d", multiplicacao);
}
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é que o *console* não abre para que eu possa adicionar os valores, quando abre não me trás o resultado, apenas aparece o CMD para adicionar as variáveis `num1` e `num2` e depois fecha.

E me traz a informação *"Info: Nothing to build for programas C"*

Estou utilizando o Eclipse como IDE.

Comment: usa o `system("pause")` no final da função (precisa da biblioteca `#include <stdlib.h>`)

Comment: uma função alternativa é usar o `getChar();`, que ai ele nem precisa de uma nova biblioteca

Answer (score 0):

O seu CMD está apenas executando o que está sendo pedido e fechando o aplicativo assim que ele termina de ler as informações. Basicamente ele não sabe que deve continuar aberto para você ler o código.

Uma solução bastante utilizada para solucionar esse tipo de problema é utilizando o `system("pause");`. Dessa forma, seu código ficaria assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int num1, num2, soma, multiplicacao;

int main(){
    printf("informe primeiro número: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("informe segundo número: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    soma = num1 + num2;
    multiplicacao = soma * num1;

    printf("o resultado é %d", multiplicacao);
    system("pause");
}
```

Apesar dessa solução já resolver seu problema, em alguns fóruns é comum encontrar pessoas que são contra esse comando, um dos principais motivos é por que você precisa importar uma nova biblioteca ao projeto.

Um comando alternativo a esse é o `getChar();` , onde ele fica esperando "um scanf vazio", então o mesmo não fecha o console até que você pressione o enter (e não precisa de uma biblioteca adicional). Na segunda solução, você só precisaria alterar as duas ultimas linhas, assim:

```c
  printf("o resultado é %d", multiplicacao);
  getChar();
```